# How to download depth image in vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I need to download depth image each frame at the end of a frame. That's why I created depth image with usage

```
VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT |
VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT
```

Then I transitioned depth image layout using vkCmdPipelineBarrier to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL instead of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL.

And here is the function that does depth download (whole file - https://pastebin.com/vfZCYNf9):

```
s32 vkdepth_get_depth_data(r32 *outData) {
    VkDevice device = vgmain_get_device();
    VkQueue graphicsQueue = vgmain_get_graphics_queue();
    VkImage depthImage = vgmain_get_depth_image();

    VkExtent2D extent = vgmain_get_swap_chain_extent();
    VkDeviceSize imageSize = extent.width * extent.height * 4;

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;

    //create staging buffer as src for image
    vmem_createBuffer(&stagingBuffer, &stagingBufferMemory, imageSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

    VkCommandPool commandPool = vgmain_get_prim_command_pool();

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = vkcmd_beginSingleTimeCommands(commandPool, device);

    VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
    region.bufferOffset = 0;
    region.bufferRowLength = 0;
    region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    region.imageOffset = (VkOffset3D){0, 0, 0};
    region.imageExtent = (VkExtent3D){
        extent.width,
        extent.height,
        1
    };

    vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(commandBuffer, depthImage,
                           VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                           stagingBuffer, 1, &region);

    vkcmd_endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer, commandPool, device, graphicsQueue);

    void *data;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
    memcpy(outData, data, imageSize);
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
}
```

Function execution for the first frame gives validation error:

> Validation layer: vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(): Cannot read invalid region
>   of memory allocation 0x8e for bound Image object 0x8d, please fill the
>   memory before using.

And for the second frame it tells me:

> Validation layer: Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (0x8d)
>   [sub-resource: aspectMask 0x2 array layer 0, mip level 0], with layout
>   VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL when first use is
>   VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL. 
>   Validation layer:
>   vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(): Cannot read invalid region of memory
>   allocation 0x8e for bound Image object 0x8d, please fill the memory
>   before using.

0x8d is depthImage, 0x8e is depthImageMemory.

1. Why my region is wrong?
2. Why it complains about layout? I transitioned depthImage layout to transfer_src_optimal and I get error with depth_stencil_attachment_optimal.
3. Is there another way of downloading depth? Via render pass store_op?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/7yhvep/retrieve_depth_attachment_from_framebuffer/

If this won't help, I can have a look at Your code later.

Comment: Ekzuzy, thanks for the link! I forgot to change finalLayout of depth attachment on render pass to transfer_src_optimal. This fixed validation errors: depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Is Your render pass setup correct? Is depth test working properly? Because validation layers error suggests that nothing was rendered into the image. And for Your doubts in one of Your comments - yes, it is valid to copy from image with optimal tiling into a buffer.

Comment: Yes, I have a working code now. I guess, I will make an answer in case someone finds it via google.

Comment: What did You change? Was setting the value of the final layout enough? Or did You have to change something else too?

Comment: Yes, setting finalLayout to transfer_src_optimal fixed the layout error. Invalid region was caused by reading depthImage before it was filled with data (before rendering first frame).

Comment: Good to know that Your problem is solved now. Good luck with the rest of Your development ;-).